# How to use mod_rewrite to write SEO friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been at this for about 4 hours now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my url:
http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs.php?seo_url=retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy

I want it to be this:
http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs/retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy

Here is my .htaccess mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1
```

Any help is much appreciated!  I have already verified mod_rewrite is enabled/turned on with my Apache server.

Comment: Your regular expressions appear to be looking for the part that comes after `seo_url=`, but you've used `^` to anchor them to the beginning of the URL, so they are never going to match.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow....

Comment: Your rules, as written, will work only for URLs like http://localhost/retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy

Comment: So I've changed the rule to be the following:  RewriteRule /mywebsite/public/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1
RewriteRule /mywebsite/public/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1  And it's still not getting there

Comment: Why have you not included the `jobs` part of the URL?

Comment: Also, the leading slash is not part of what `mod_rewrite` looks at, so including that in the "match" part of your rule is going to mean that it doesn't match.

Comment: RewriteRule mywebsite/public/jobs([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1 
RewriteRule mywebsite/public/jobs([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ jobs.php?seo_url=$1  This was my most recent attempt, still not working

Comment: You don't have a slash between `jobs` and the regex. And unless the result is supposed to be `http: //localhost/jobs.php?seo_url=...`, you need to include more in the result side of things too.

Comment: There is no slash after jobs.  See my original url above.    Existing url:  http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs.php?seo_url=retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy    URL I WANT:  http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs/retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy

Comment: Where are you putting your .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess is in the root folder for this website.  In other words, I have several projects on my localhost, this particular one is inside the root for "mywebsite" project.    The following test works, so I think it's in the right spot...    RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [L,R]

Comment: When you say "you want", that's the URL people should be putting in their browser, while the one with "seo_url=" is the one that should be handed to your code? The one you want is what you're trying to match against, which clearly does have a slash after `jobs`.

Comment: Yes, the user clicks on a link, bringing them to the job detail page.  I don't want to see all the parameters from the $_GET request (jobs.php?id=454)... I want the SEO friendly version to show in the url.  I have created a slug in my database that has the URL friendly version and I'm going crazy trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got mine to work with my website

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^mywebsite/public/jobs/(.+)/?$ /mywebsite/public/jobs.php?seo_url=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Did this a while ago but learnt from here

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It's still not working for me.  I'll take a look at the link you sent.  This is the most frustrating thing.

Comment: Yeah I had similar issues, was a pain to get working the way I wanted. What part isn't working? Can you echo $_GET['seo_url']?

Comment: Yes, I can echo $_GET['seo-url'].  So right now, the url looks like this: http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs.php?seo_url=retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy    I would like the url to look like this:  http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs/retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy.  So I'm basically trying to replace ".php?seo_url=" with a slash "/"

Comment: are you getting the expected result?

Comment: If you are your rewrite rules might be working but you may have issues in your PHP code or sql query

Comment: Yep, I am getting the correct results from my database and _$GET request, but the url is not what I want

Comment: http://localhost/mywebsite/public/jobs/retail-store-manager-mr-nice-guy I'm talking about from this url?

Comment: No, that does not give me the correct results when clicking on that link.  And the _$GET['seo-url'] goes away also.